# Merging XML nodes

Tags: xslt

I have a source xml in the following format:

```
 <xml>
   <node>
         <va-name>
               <source area="RSC1985s5c1"/>
         </va-name>
         <body>
              <div >
                  <heading>heading 1</heading>
               </div>
         </body>
   </node>
   <node>
         <va-name>
               <source area="RSC1985s5c2"/>
         </va-name>
         <body>
              <div >
                  <heading>heading 2</heading>
               </div>
         </body>
   </node>

   <node>
         <va-name>
               <source area="RSC1985s5c1"/>
         </va-name>
         <body>
              <div >
                  <heading>heading 3</heading>
               </div>
         </body>
   </node>

<xml>
```

What i want is to merge the nodes if xml/node/va-name/source[@area] values are equal among differnent xml/node. I have to copy only the xml/node/body and merge them into first node.

Output should be:

```
 <xml>
   <node>
         <va-name>
               <source area="RSC1985s5c1"/>
         </va-name>
         <body>
              <div >
                  <heading> heading 1 </heading>
               </div>
               <div >
                  <heading> heading 3 </heading>
               </div>
         </body>
   </node>
    <node>
         <va-name>
               <source area="RSC1985s5c2"/>
         </va-name>
         <body>
              <div >
                  <heading>heading 2</heading>
               </div>
         </body>
   </node>
 </xml>
```

In above output, the node 1 and node 3 has a same xml/node/va-name/source[@area] that's why in the output i have combined both and node 2 will be output as it is. If i have more nodes and if any one of them matched (xml/node/va-name/source[@area]) wih node 2 then we will combine it to node 2 and so on...

Appreciate if i can get any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy grouping solution in XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="xml">
<xml>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node" group-by="va-name/source/@area">
  <node>
    <xsl:copy-of select="va-name"/>
    <body>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/body/*"/>
    </body>
  </node>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xml>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you Micheal, just modified little bit to output va-name, source nodes  as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is YAGP (Yet Another Grouping Problem) best solved using the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). This stylesheet produces the desired output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="byArea" match="node" use="va-name/source/@area" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template
        match="node[generate-id()=
                    generate-id(key('byArea', va-name/source/@area)[1])]">
        <node>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="va-name" />
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('byArea', va-name/source/@area)"
                    mode="out" />
            </body>
        </node>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node" mode="out">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="body/div" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The OP didn't say there was a constraint to use XSLT 1.0. Grouping problems are much easier in 2.0.

Comment: @Michael - Excellent point. Maybe the OP can tell us which version of XSLT is required?

Comment: Thanks Lwburk, i am using xslt 2.0 but did try you script as well and it's working perfectly.

Comment: @atif - No problem. Michael's is definitely the solution you want to use if you're on XSLT 2.0. I'll leave this here as a relic in case someone who needs a 1.0 solution stumbles upon it.